How to update multiple control labels on a form without having repetitive code and unnecessary loops and functions in C# ,Net
I have a bunch of labels on a form that needs updating its Text property from variables. I don't want to repetitively write out each control .Text and assign the values and variables.
This is the code that is easiest to write, but harder to maintain, and takes up so much space:
if (AccountIndex == 1) {LabelA1.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;}
if (AccountIndex == 2) {LabelA2.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;}
if (AccountIndex == 3) {LabelA3.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;}

if (AccountIndex == 1) {LabelB1.Text = "Text :" + varSomethingElse;}
if (AccountIndex == 2) {LabelB2.Text = "Text :" + varSomethingElse;}
if (AccountIndex == 3) {LabelB3.Text = "Text :" + varSomethingElse;}

The variable values are different for the AccountIndex values. Is there a way to write it more concisely and be easier to maintain and extend?
Answering my own question: Consider replacing each block above with two lines of code that stays 2 lines no matter how many iterations you add:
var LabelA = this.Controls.Find($"LabelA{i}", true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Windows.Forms.Label; 
if (LabelA != null) LabelA.Text = "Text :" + varSomething; 
var LabelB = this.Controls.Find($"LabelB{i}", true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Windows.Forms.Label; 
if (LabelB != null) LabelB.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;

It is assumed you have an index variable to iterate through the 2 sets (i) or more.

Answering my own question: Consider replacing each block above with two lines of code that stays 2 lines no matter how many iterations you add:
var LabelA = this.Controls.Find($"LabelA{i}", true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Windows.Forms.Label;
if (LabelA != null) LabelA.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;
var LabelB = this.Controls.Find($"LabelB{i}", true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Windows.Forms.Label;
if (LabelB != null) LabelB.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;
It is assumed you have an index variable to iterate through the 2 sets (i).

One option is to create a collection of "label controls" (that you can iterate) when they're created or after loading.

You can write this code in single line, like this :
LabelA1.Text = LabelA2.Text = LabelA3.Text = "Text :" + varSomething;

LabelB1.Text = LabelB2.Text = LabelB3.Text = "Text :" + varSomethingElse;


You can refer this answer also : Assign same value to multiple variables in single statement


I have clarified that there is different AccountIndex where variables though the same contains different values relevant for setting the text.
